# Why does closedness and boundedness for $S = \{ v \in V : || v||_{\infty} = 1\}$ imply that $S$ is compact in a finite dimensional vector space $V$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space, with basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$, over the reals $\mathbb R$ and $|| v ||_{\infty} = || a_1 e_1 + \ldots + a_n e_n||_{\infty}=\max_{1 \le k \le n} |a_k|$ is a norm.

It is then stated that $S = \{ v \in V : || v||_{\infty} = 1\}$ is closed and bounded with respect to $|| \cdot ||_{\infty}$.

This is the case because it is closed with respect to the topology induced by the metric $d(x,y) = ||x-y||_{\infty}$ ??

Next, why does **closedness** and **boundedness** for $S$ imply that $S$ is **compact** ? I know this is true if $S \subset \mathbb R^n$, but in this case $S\subset V$.

My considerations is due to the following proof (in danish), that every norm on a finite dimensional vector space induce equivalent metrics:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For french mathematicians a compact is by definition separated (two distinct points admit disjoint neighborhoods which is essential for the uniqueness of limits) and for american mathematicians it is not. This presents sometimes difficulties to the beginners reading from both sources (Example: a set with the trivial topology is compact for americans while it is not for frenchs)

Answer (score 1):

You can identify $V$ with $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Is this not what is trying to be proved? I can't tell because I can't read Danish, but I think that's what OP means when they say *"My considerations is due to the following proof (in danish), that every norm on a finite dimensional vector space induce equivalent metrics:"*.

Comment: This is done with respect to the scalars, that if $v = a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_n v_n$ then $v$ corresponds to $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ ? Is this enough to justify that $S$ is closed ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a basis $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ of $V$ and identify $V$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ as following.

- Define a linear map $\varphi:V\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ by setting $\varphi(a_{1}v_{1}+...+a_{n}v_{n})=(a_{1},...,a_{n})$.
- Since $v_{1},...,v_{n}$ is a basis then this map is $1$-to-$1$ and onto.
- By putting the norm $\|a_{1}v_{1}+...+a_{n}v_{n}\|_{2}=\sqrt{a_{1}^{2}+...+a_{n}^{2}}$ on $V$ you see that this map is also a homeomorphism since $\|\varphi(v)\|_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}=\|v\|_{2}$ for all $v\in V$ and $\varphi$ is linear.

This identification implies that a subset of $V$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. Since all norms in $V$ are equivalent and compactness is a topological property, then a subset of $V$ under the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Then $S$ is the preimage of $\{1\}$ under the continuous function $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}:V\to\mathbb{R}$, and is thus closed. And the diameter is clearly bounded by $2$ under the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$.